# AngularJS routing not picking up routes

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am having some issues routing.  I have my main app.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['budget']);

angular
    .module('app')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

and my controller file looks like:

```
angular
.module('budget', ['budget.services'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/content/app/budget/views/budget.html',
            controller: 'budget.homeController'
        })
        .when('/budget/:year/:month',
        {
            templateUrl: '/content/app/budget/views/budget.html',
            controller: 'budget.homeSelectController'
        });
}])

.controller('budget.homeController', function ($scope, budgetStore) {
    budgetStore.getCurrentBudget(function (data) {
        $scope.budget = data;
    });
})
.controller('budget.homeSelectController', function ($scope, $routeParams, budgetStore) {
    budgetStore.getBudget($routeParams.month, $routeParams.year, function (data) {
        $scope.budget = data;
    });
});
```

Angular only ever routes to the homeController route, it never routes to the second route?  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why are you configuring routes inside `budget` module and not inside the `app` module?

Comment: can you setup a plunk showing the problem

Comment: Did you put correct querystring for this url `.when('/budget/:year/:month',
        {`?

Comment: I didn't want to put all on my routing and controllers in one file, so  I've opted to spread it out over several files.  And it is not a problem with querystrings because if I load this all into one file during app's definition it all works.  It seems to be a problem in spreading out my configuration/modules over several files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong query string assigning

Did you check this?

> pass query string in angular js

```
<a href="/main.html#/budget/12/12" >Next Page</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/main.html#/budget/{{Yourvale1}}/{{Yourvale2}}" >Next Page</a>
```

Get Query String Value

```
$routeParams.Yourvale1;
```

Comment: I have tried adding several different routes in i.e. /Budget2 and angularJS ignores it so I end up with http://localhost/#%2Fbudget2  So I don't think it's a problem with the query parameters.

Comment: Am 100% surely think about it'a a routing issue. Can you show me your link button which you where pass the query parameters?

Comment: <li><a href="#/budget/{{budget.previousYear}}/{{budget.previousMonth}}">«</a></li>

Comment: But as I've said above, if I bung this all in one file, it works.  It's only as I've split it out that I'm having the issue.

Comment: `<li><a href="#/budget/{{budget.previousYear}}/{{budget.previousMonth}}">«</a></li>` this is correct for my answer, Now does it working or not? Shoild be the route parms names are same.

Comment: But Ramesh, it doesn't matter about params because if I add the route /#/Budget2 and a controller in the separate file I get the same issue.  So this wouldn't solve my problem.  Whether it includes params or not, I am unable to set up a second route in this second module.

Comment: Okay change your `homeSelectController` name to `SelectController`, Then try it

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand that bit.  Why would the name change work?

Comment: Two controller name starting with home , Some time i got this problem, Did you checkout that?

Comment: I did, it didn't make any difference

Comment: hmm ! i think your controller called, did you check  the controller called using debugger?